# How can I remove/add a role from/to a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

This is how I want it to work. How **does** it work?

```
userManager.RemoveRole(oldAdminUser, "GroupAdmin");
userManager.RemoveRole(newAdminUser, "GroupUser");
userManager.AddRole(oldAdminUser, "GroupUser");
userManager.AddRole(newAdminUser, "GroupAdmin");
```

In the fantasy example above, two users swap roles. The old admin becomes a user, and the old user becomes the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(oldAdminUser, "GroupAdmin");
await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(newAdminUser, "GroupUser");
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(oldAdminUser, "GroupUser");
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newAdminUser, "GroupAdmin");
```

Comment: Oh, it wasn't more complicated than that... Well, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Role Controller class, You have to add a dependency of `RoleManager` class to the Constructor.

The `RoleManager` class is used to manage the Roles in Identity, and has the some important functions and properties. The `role` is an object of type `IdentityRole`.

Example of creating and deleting roles:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Required]string name)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(name));
                if (result.Succeeded)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                else
                    Errors(result);
            }
            return View(name);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            IdentityRole role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (role != null)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                else
                    Errors(result);
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "No role found");
            return View("Index", roleManager.Roles);
        }
```

Then you can use the following members of the `UserManager` class to play with the roles:

`userManager.AddToRoleAsync(AppUser user, string name)`

`userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(AppUser user, string name)`

etc.

You can read full arcticle [here](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-roles/)